# Basic HTTP server

Tags: node.js, express

I wanted to create a simple and secure HTTP web server.

I used the example found on this question "[Basic static file server in NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7268033/basic-status-file-server-in-nodejs)" and updated / changed some parts here and there.

Here's the code :

```
var http = require('http'),
    url = require('url'),
    fs = require('fs');

function error404(res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.write('404 Not Found\n');
    res.end();
}

http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    var path = url.parse(req.url).pathname.toLowerCase().split('/');
    var file = path[path.length - 1]
    var filename = file.split('.');
    var extension = filename[filename.length - 1];
    if(extension === 'html') {
        fs.exists('./client/' + file, function(exists) {
            if(!exists) { error404(res); }
            else {
                res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
                var fileStream = fs.createReadStream('./client/' + file);
                fileStream.pipe(res);
                return;
            }
        });
    }
    else if(extension === 'js') {
        fs.exists('./client/js/' + file, function(exists) {
            if(!exists) { error404(res); }
            else {
                res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/javascript'});
                var fileStream = fs.createReadStream('./client/js/' + file);
                fileStream.pipe(res);
                return;
            }
        });
    }
    else if(extension === 'css') {
        fs.exists('./client/css/' + file, function(exists) {
            if(!exists) { error404(res); }
            else {
                res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/css'});
                var fileStream = fs.createReadStream('./client/css/' + file);
                fileStream.pipe(res);
                return;
            }
        });
    }
    else { error404(res); }
}).listen(8080);
```

Now I have three questions :

- 1) Would this piece of code create a secure server and reliable ?
- 2) What could be improved ?
- 3) What are the advantages of using Express.js compared to this combined with "Connect" ?

Thank you a lot in advance !

(Info : I count on using this code later combined with "Handlebars", "Socket.io" and "Mongoose / MongoDB".)

Comment: You should go over there to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ and post your question there.

Comment: I knew about codereview but there doesn't seem to be many people using node.js on that site (33 threads with that tag).

Comment: Well...if you want a secure and simple webserver, use lighttpd. ;) It's much better evaluated and revised than your implementation will ever be.

Comment: why do you want to reinvent the wheel? use the and contribute to the already existing solutions like [node-static](https://github.com/cloudhead/node-static), [http-server](https://github.com/nodeapps/http-server), [send](https://github.com/visionmedia/send).

Comment: Yes, but lighttpd doesn't use node.js though and I want to use this basic server and then continue to write my web site.

Answer (score -3):

You should definitely just use express.

Otherwise, you'll waste a lot of your time reinventing the wheel.

Comment: The third part of your question literally says "3) What are the advantages of using Express.js compared to this combined with "Connect"?" If you didn't want reasons to use express instead (eg, not wasting time), then you shouldn't have asked.

Comment: You didn't give any reason. You just told me to switch to Express without providing any feature comparison. I like to know what I use and just using Express where I don't know the code base and has a lot more features than I actually need isn't really worth it.

Comment: The fact that a solution already exists is one thing, but I already knew about it so it meant that there was a deeper reason behind my question. The reason I asked this question is because I was trying to build a server by myself to understand the code-base not just  mindlessly copy / paste something I don't. It's great to use libraries and frameworks but there is a point where you stacked so much technologies you don't understand the inner-workings off that if a problem occurs, you won't have the faintest idea of what to do.

Comment: I would suggest that it would take less time to familiarize yourself with the source of express than to build anything resembling a useful (browser-facing) server that, as you mentioned, supports socket.io (which was built to work well with express). Also, keep in mind that express is a very light framework itself - nothing even approaching Rails. It's like a light sinatra. For example, instantiating a whole express server and listening on a port takes 0.143s on my macbook air. Startup of a vanilla node http server instance takes 0.073s.