# Serve jpeg file in node without framework

Tags: javascript, node.js, jpeg

I am trying to learn the ins and outs of node. I know you can serve a file with a framework but I am trying to do it manually. I have a jpeg file in './public/logo.jpg'. When I send the request through localhost:8080 I don't get the image, just a blank screen with a generic image placeholder. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

```
var http=require('http');
var url=require('url');
var fs=require('fs');

// creates a new httpServer instance
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
// this is the callback, or request handler for the httpServer
log('in server callback')
res.ins=res.write;

var parse=url.parse(req.url,true);
var path0=parse.pathname;
console.log(path0)
// respond to the browser, write some headers so the 
// browser knows what type of content we are sending

var serveFile=function(){
    var path='./public'+path0
    fs.exists(path,function(e){
        if(e){
            log('serving file')
            log(path)
            fs.readFile(path,'binary',function(err,data){
                if(data){
                    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg'});
                    res.ins(data)
                    res.end()
                }
            })
        }
        else{
            log('no file to serve')
            log(path)
            servePage()
        }   
    })
}
serveFile()
}).listen(8080); // the server will listen on port 8080
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Basic static file server in NodeJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7268033/basic-static-file-server-in-nodejs)

Comment: As long as I change the encoding to 'utf8' and alter the mime the above code works for css files and js files, just not for image files. The link you gave uses 'createFileStream' as opposed to 'readFile'. Is there something about images that is incompatible with 'readFile'? Thanks

Comment: When you use readFile it will load whole file into memory before sending over the network. But if you use stream with pipe, it will just 'pipe' stream to network and directly output IO from file to socket stream, which is much more efficient especially for big files. With high load and readFile your server will not be able to handle too much files due to RAM limits. While this is not the same case with streams.

Answer (score 0):

Simply change the following two lines in your `readFile` callback :

```
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg'});
res.write(data, 'binary');
```

Use `response.write` to send data to the client and set encoding to `binary`. (Default is utf-8)