# Parse Hosting static file URL aliases

Tags: node.js, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ember.js, parse-platform

I'm trying to set up Parse hosting (which is based on node.js) to handle certain URLs by returning a specific static file. This is to make it work with Ember.js history based routing (http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/specifying-the-location-api/).

So for example: I want all the following URLs to load the root `index.html` without doing a 301 redirect:

`domain.com/search`
`domain.com/about`
`domain.com/some-other-route`

This is easily doable in an Apache .htaccess rewrite rule. Is there something similar I can use with Parse hosting? Or do I have to write my own code that handles those URLs and return the file I want somehow?

Let me know if my description is not clear and I'll try to add more details.

Comment: You should be careful. Many URLs loading the same page will lead to duplicate content and that's not what you want

Comment: @JustinIurman I understand that. But that's specifically what the Ember docs are saying: "Keep in mind that your server must serve the Ember app at all the routes defined here" from the above link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Express on Parse and have it render your `index.html` as if it were an `EJS` view.
Either copy your `index.html` to `cloud/views/index.ejs` or sym-link it to the same location.

```
// cloud/main.js
require('cloud/app.js');
```

Then

```
// cloud/app.js

var express = require('express');

var app = express();
app.set('views','cloud/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index.ejs');
});

app.listen();
```

I'd been looking for an answer to this question FOREVER, and turns out the [Google Group for Parse.com](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/parse-developers) seems more active than Parsers on Stack Overflow.  Found this answer [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/parse-developers/index.html/parse-developers/OKuwunbs4cg/6XCwTaIJ-qwJ).

Comment: In your code example, wouldn't GET '/*' interfere with loading css and js files that are in the public directory? or does the public folder have higher priority than express routes?

Comment: Nevermind. I tested and it seems the public directory has priority.

Answer (score 0):

I have found this answer. You can change the filename. If filename=="search" then filename="index.html", and this way you get a different file.
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7268033/basic-static-file-server-in-nodejs)