# How to get what's been requested in node.js server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web

I want to create a pure node.js server and serve the requested file. But I don't know how to read the GET request to use it on an if else statement to serve the correct file.

Something like:

```
http.createServer(function(req,res){
      if(req==="thing.txt"){
      fs.readFile('thing.txt', function(err, data) {
      res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
      res.write(data);
      res.end();
  });}else{}
  }).listen(8080);
```

Comment: No Express Please. Just pure Node

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7268033/basic-static-file-server-in-nodejs