# unable to create simple websocket - NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I am trying to follow this tutorial: https://www.simonewebdesign.it/101-web-socket-protocol-handshake/ for developing simple websocket protocol.

I am visiting `localhost:1337/index.html` but I get:

> This localhost page can’t be found
>
> No web page was found for the web address: http://localhost:1337/index.html
>       Search Google for localhost 1337 index
>       HTTP ERROR 404

if I visit this url: `file:///C:/Users/.../websocket-demo/index.html`

I atleast see the index.html page being rendered. But in console I get this error:

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:1337/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

I am not sure what's wrong?

I have 3 files: `index.html`, `server.js` and `client.js`

## server.js

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
var WebSocketServer = require('websocket').server;
var http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  console.log('Received request from ' + request.url);
  response.writeHead(404);
  response.end();
});

server.listen(1337, function() {
    console.log('Server is listening on port 1337.');
});

wsServer = new WebSocketServer({
    httpServer: server,
    autoAcceptConnections: false // because security matters
});

function isAllowedOrigin(origin) {
  console.log('Connection requested from origin ' + origin);

  valid_origins = [
    'http://localhost:8080',
    '127.0.0.1',
    'null'
  ];

  if (valid_origins.indexOf(origin) != -1) {
    console.log('Connection accepted from origin ' + origin);
    return true;
  }

  console.log('Origin ' + origin + ' is not allowed.')
  return false;
}

wsServer.on('connection', function(webSocketConnection) {
  console.log('Connection started.');
});

wsServer.on('request', function(request) {

  var connection = isAllowedOrigin(request.origin) ?
    request.accept('echo-protocol', request.origin)
    : request.reject();

  connection.on('message', function(message) {

    var response = '';
    console.log('Received Message: ' + message.utf8Data);

    if (message.type === 'utf8') {

      switch (message.utf8Data) {
        case 'hi':
          response = 'Hey there';
          break;
        case 'hello':
          response = 'Heya!';
          break;
        case 'xyzzy':
          response = 'Nothing happens.';
          break;
        case 'desu':
          response = 'Keep typing, man. Keep typing.';
          break;
        default:
          response = "Hello. Uh... what am I supposed to do with '" +
          message.utf8Data + "'?";
      }
      connection.sendUTF(response);
    }
  });
  connection.on('close', function(reasonCode, description) {
      console.log(connection.remoteAddress + ' has been disconnected.');
  });
});
```

## client.js

```
(function () {

  var ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:1337', 'echo-protocol');

  ws.onopen = function (event) {
    console.log('Connection opened.');
  }

  ws.onmessage = function (event) {
    console.log('Response from server: ' + event.data);
  }

  ws.onclose = function (event) {
    console.log('Connection closed.');
  }

  ws.onerror = function (event) {
    console.log('An error occurred. Sorry for that.');
  }

  WebSocket.prototype.sendMessage = function (message) {
    this.send(message);
    console.log('Message sent: ' + message);
  }

  document.getElementById('send').addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var message = document.getElementById('message').value;
    ws.sendMessage(message);
  });

})();
```

## index.html - consist of forms

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>WebSocket Client Demo</title>
</head>
<body>

  <h1>WebSocket Client</h1>

  <form>
    <label for="message">Send a message</label>
    <input id="message" name="message" type="text">
    <button id="send" name="send">Send</button>
  </form>

  <script src="client.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your web server doesn't serve your `index.html` file.

You can see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7268033/basic-static-file-server-in-nodejs) to get an idea how to serve static files, or you can just boot up another HTTP server to serve your index file, like with python, the way they suggested in the README file of the tutorial that you are following: https://github.com/simonewebdesign/websocket-demo